# Probability of falling at least 3 equal color balls

Tags: probability

There is 36 balls. 12 red, 12 blue and 12 yellow.

We pick 6 random balls.

I need a probability of falling at least 3 equal color, so it means 3 red or more red, or 3 yellow or more yellow, or 3 blue or more blue.

I have calculated probability of falling 3 or more red balls which is ~0.3 (same probability for yellow and blue because there)

**So is this calculated this way since its OR: 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3 = 0.9 ?**

One thing which makes me thing there is something bad is that we get more than 100% if we formulate problem this with 2 or 1 ball for example:

I need a probability of falling 2 red or more red, or 2 yellow or more yellow, or 2 blue or more blue.

I have calculated that chance of falling 2 or more red balls is 0.6602327. So 0.6602327 * 3 = over 1. And it should be 100% because by picking 6 balls we always will have at least 2 equal color.

Comment: Since you are taking the set union, simply adding will make the intersection (in your case both 3 red, 3 blue balls fall or 2+ red, 2+ blue etc.) counted twice. $P$(3 red OR 3 blue) $=$ $P$(3 red)$+ P$(3 blue)$- P$(3 red AND 3 blue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  the only way to **not** obtain at least three balls of the same color is if two balls of each color are selected; i.e., you pick $(r,r,b,b,y,y)$ in some order.

Comment: So 1 - P (RRBBYY) ? 1 - 12C2 * 12C2 * 12C2 / 36C6 = 0.85239887256

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: But I assume I cannot find some similar idea if now I want at least 4 and 5 any equal color balls. I am trying to think, but I might end up with adding same sets twice again as varun mentioned, but did not understand fully it yet how should i deal. SHould I maybe make another topic?

Comment: Just read that if the events are mutually exclusive (it is not possible to be 4 reds and 4 yellows or blues at the same time) we can add them and we will not have added twice. http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-events-mutually-exclusive.html